# Do javascript console debugger commands follow w3c recommendation / specifications?

Tags: javascript, console, w3c, w3c-validation

I searched a lot over Internet. Majorly on w3c sites [here](http://www.w3.org/2011/08/browser-testing-charter.html). But no satisfactory links.

So Do people around have idea whether several console commands like below:

```
console.log("test");
console.debug("test1");
window.console.log("tested on ie"). // (IE Specific? ) Syntax sometimes cross browser different.
```

follows **W3C specification?** Are they formally specified ?

Comment: nope: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log#Specification

Comment: The w3c's Browser Testing and Tools Working Group is chartered to work on a specification for it, but it has been since 2011 and it seems little or no progress has been made in that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not all browsers support console.log as it is not part of the standard and is an extension of the DOM and thus you should not count on its presence. To make your code resilient you should assume it does not exist and code accordingly. 
console.log should be used only in debuggind process.